# Changing encoding to utf8

Tags: mysql

We wanna change the db to utf8 on db and table level. Important is that I can not use the dbname because it can be set by the migration tool so i need to retrieve it from the database() function....

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UpdateToUTF8;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateToUTF8 ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE Finished BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE TableName TEXT;


  DECLARE TablesCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT c1.TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES c1
    WHERE c1.TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND c1.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Finished = TRUE;

  OPEN TablesCursor;

  MainLoop: LOOP
    FETCH TablesCursor INTO TableName;
    IF Finished THEN
      LEAVE MainLoop;
    END IF;

    SET @tableUpdateQuery = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TableName, '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;');
    PREPARE tableUpdate  FROM @tableUpdateQuery;
    EXECUTE tableUpdate;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE tableupdate;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE TablesCursor;

  SET @DataBaseName = database();

  ALTER DATABASE @DataBaseName CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
END //
DELIMITER ;

SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
CALL UpdateToUTF8();
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Throws following error:

```
[2019-05-01 16:22:38] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@DataBaseName CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
[2019-05-01 16:22:38] #SET @schemaUpdateQ' at line 32
```

We also tried `ALTER DATABASE (SELECT database()) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: *"i need to retrieve it from the database() function"* that idea might backfire on you.  Yes it is true you can set the default working database with `USE database` and use `DATABASE()` would give the working database. One possible problem for you is that PROCEDURE's can be called across databases so `DATABASE()` would then contain the schema/database name where the PROCEDURE was created and not the working database which was set with `USE database`

Comment: We use flyaway as a db migration toll and in the tool you can set the working database. And this procedure will only be called in the migration so no it won't backfire